# How to get Ajax search results above another div element?

Tags: html, css

I am struggling with the positioning my search results on top of other divs. You can view screen recording here to see the problem:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kU_vl2ZAmSCok0pxnTTvYhacxqcZZ9m_/view?usp=sharing

These are the search entries:

```html
{% if results|length %}
<div id="instant-results">
    <ul class="list-unstyled result-bucket" >
        {% for r in results %}
        <li class="result-entry" data-suggestion="{% cycle 'Target 1' 'Target 2' 'Target 3' %}" data-position="1" data-type="type" data-analytics-type="merchant">
            <a href="{{ r.url }}" class="result-link">
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left">
                        <img src="http://mellon.co.tz/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/noimage.gif" class="media-object">
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">{{ r.title }}</h4>
                        <p>Nationality: {{ r.owner.get_nationality_display }} | Age: {{ r.owner.age }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
{% endfor %}    
</div>
```

This is the section on the webpage:

```html
<section class="d-lg-table bg-secondary">
        <div class="d-none d-lg-table-cell align-middle w-50 bg-center bg-no-repeat bg-cover text-center" style="background-image: url({% static 'images/slider/messi.jpg' %});"><a class="video-player-button" href="https://player.vimeo.com/video/93641234?color=ac32e4&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" data-fancybox data-width="1000" data-height="563"><i class="fe-icon-play"></i></a><span class="d-block video-player-label text-muted pt-3">Click me to watch video!</span></div>
        <div class="d-lg-table-cell py-5 my-lg-5 px-2 px-lg-5  bg-gradient-1">
          <div class="p-3">
            <h2 class="h3 block-title mb-4 heading-white">Search for a player</h2>
            <p class="text-muted pb-4">Start typing and the results will appear immediately! Start typing and the results will appear immediately! Start typing and the results will appear immediately!</p>
            <div class="wizard">
            <input type="text" id="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for a player..."  autocomplete="off"/>        
              <div id="results"></div>     
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

I know I have to do something with z-index and position but I am not sure what exactly.

The CSS:

```css
/*---------- Search ----------*/
.result-bucket li {
    padding: 7px 15px;
}
.instant-results {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    color: gray;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
    display: none;
    z-index: 10;
}
.form-search {
    transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}
.search-form {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.result-link {
    text-decoration:none!important;
}
.result-link .media-body {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: gray;
}
.result-link .media-heading {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.result-link .media-object {
    width: 50px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-right:10px;
    border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.result-entry + .result-entry {
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
}

.wizard {
    position: relative!important;
}

#results {
    postion: absolute!important;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50px; /* Height of input */
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: You would have to make the search results box parent position:relative with css and make the result box position absolute. You would then have to position it of course. z-index only needs to be used if something is covering the results.

Answer (score 2):

"position:absolute" may help. The CSS below sets the results parent position to relative. This allows you to position the results box absolute but relative to the ".wizard" container since its a child.

Note that "position: absolute" brings the #results container out of the document flow (but positioned relative to ".wizard") and should appear above other elements in the z-index. If it does not you may have to tweak the z-index (making it a higher index).

```
.wizard {
    position: relative;
}

#results {
    postion: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50px; /* Height of input */
    left: 0;
}
```

If you show an example of your current css applied to these elements it will help a bit with troubleshooting.

Comment: Agreed Derek. Only thing I would add to this would be changing to the top value to `top: 100%;`. As the results are inside the relative div, top 100% will position it underneath the input exactly, without the need for fixed values. Just in case the input size happens to change in the future ;)

Comment: Unfortunately this CSS did not work.. `postion: absolute;` get's crossed out I can see in my chrome dev tools. Even adding `!important` does not work. Any ideas what is going wrong? I add all the CSS files to my original post, maybe it helps.

Comment: Also removing the `position: abosolute` in `instant-results` and `position:relative` in `search-form` did not work.

Comment: Look in inspector and look to see whats creating the position style and overriding it. Look for a position style thats not crossed out for that element.